# Running .net core application with IBM ILOG CPLEX 12.9 in linux doesn't work

Tags: linux, dll, .net-core, mathematical-optimization, cplex

I have a .net core application that uses IBM ILOG CPLEX 12.9. It works normally on Windows 10. But when I try to run on linux (Ubuntu 18.04), the following error occurs:

System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'cp_wrap_cpp_dotnet1290' or one of its dependencies.

I installed IBM ILOG CPLEX 12.9 on Linux and the installation was successful.
Where do I find this dll (or .so)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the dotnet framework is available on Windows as can be seen at

https://www.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=E57328F0919E11E8A5E6A380334DFF95&osPlatform=Windows

but not on linux

https://www.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=BE7489907D6811E9BFD5252BC35BF06E&osPlatform=Linux

In the CPLEX documentation we can read

> The .NET examples are available in C# (extension .cs ). These examples
>   are similar to the C++ examples, except they are available for Windows
>   only.